# FFMPEG works on Console but doesn't work in PHP script on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I have this aplication where I need to convert video files to MP4 and then compress it. I'm trying to use FFMPEG to get this to work. Tried the command lines in the console and it works great

**Converting**

```
ffmpeg -i teste.avi teste.mp4
```

**Compressing**

```
ffmpeg -i teste.mp4 -acodec mp2 teste.mp4
```

But when I do the same within a PHP script, it starts yelling that something called `GLIBCXX` is not installed. This is the error:

```
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0)
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0)
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0)
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.3)
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.3)
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4)
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4)
ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4)
```

This is my script

```
$r = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $file_path $output_path 2>&1"); //convert
$r = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $file_path -acodec mp2 $file_path 2>&1"); //compress
```

I'm running the script on Ubuntu

**@edit**
I can run, for example, shell_exec('ls')

Comment: It's possible that the user which the webserver is running as doesn't have access to the libraries/files needed by ffmpeg

Comment: how can I grant such permissions to my webserver?

Comment: Did you `chown` the htdocs directory somewhere in the past? That could be a cause.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this was I went to /usr/lib and searched for libstdc++ (this directory has newer versions) and copied it to /opt/lampp/lib.

I took a backup of the original file and pasted the new file and BOOM! It worked! :)

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: what do you mena by newer version in /usr/lib

Comment: Newer versions of libstdc++.